# Running sudo (system) command from shiny server (in Shiny App)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am able to invoke sudo command from R / R Studio to provide specific permission to a path in ubuntu machine.

**Code:**

```
system('sudo -kS chmod -R 755  PATH',input="*********")
```

Here input is the password of sudo user. Now, I need to execute the same system command in Shiny App hosted in shiny server. By default shiny-server runs applications as the "shiny" user, which has lower privilege. What possible permission can be provided to "shiny" user so that this sudo code gets executed in shiny server as well.Thus , looking for ways to run system command from shiny server as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try eco

```
system(paste0("echo -e 'yourinputhere\n' | sudo -kS chmod -R 755  PATH'))
```

sudo -s option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified.